# List with distinct values inside only

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of objects with properties 
`Id` and `Name`.

```
 foreach (var x in mydata)
 {                
    var model = new MyViewModel()
    {
       Id = x.Days.Id,
       Name = x.Days.Name                                   
    };                                    
    models.Add(model);
 }
```

I'm returning list (models) which has duplicate items, how can I return list of distinct items inside?

Comment: Distinct by what ? ID ?

Comment: There are dozens of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want elements distinct by Id :

```
foreach (var x in mydata)
 {                
    var model = new MyViewModel()
    {
       Id = x.Days.Id,
       Name = x.Days.Name                                   
    };                                    
    if(!models.Contains(x=>x.Id==model.Id)
        models.Add(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashSet<T>`, something like that:

```
// Ids that was used before
HashSet<int> Ids = new HashSet<int>();

foreach (var x in mydata) {                
  // Check for duplicates
  if (Ids.Contains(x.Days.Id))
    continue; // <- duplicate
  else
    Ids.Add(x.Days.Id);

  // Your code
  var model = new MyViewModel() {
    Id = x.Days.Id,

    Name = x.Days.Name                                   
  };                                    

  models.Add(model);
}
```